# Is there a way to edit the pre stored address in the Onepage checkout page?

Tags: magento

My issues, After launching the website I have made some of the street lines mandatory, which was not initially. So some of the customers already have address stored without the new mandatory street line. So is there a Magento way to show the selected stored address in the Onepage adress form and customer can edit it and save it(Save in same ID) and continue with Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can edit the address, refer the below image, you just need to select the address and edit.
[image]

Comment: I want to do it conditionally, When an validation is failed locally(Validation ) or from server.